# MAC OS prompt won't change to show my full path

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, command-prompt

I have the following in my .bash_profile:

```
PS1='\h:\w$ '
```

But my prompt looks like this:

```
laptop:~$
```

What setting do I need to modify so that the "~" instead prints out the correct path... in this instance it should be /Users/jay/

The jay account is the default user, so is there a way to change this?

Comment: Probably better ask in the dedicated Apple [apple.se] forum. (Search for `bash prompt` - I see a few possibly relevant questions.)

Comment: This is actually a bash question, it's not specific to OS X.  And `~` **is** the correct path, it evaluates to `$HOME`.  Navigate anywhere you like and then type `cd ~`.  Guess where you'll end up...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected. Tilde is a very well known shorthand for active user's home folder.
If you look at the help for Bash

```
man bash
```

and then type ( you may need to hit 'n' key a couple of times to get to the section about PROMPTING)

```
/PROMPTING
```

You will notice that it says

```
\w     the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
\W     the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
```

That being said, if you really want it to print the full path instead, you can use another variable: *$PWD* (Peek Working Directory) to replace your \w or \W

So, type:

```
echo $PS1
```

If for example that returns

```
\h:\W \u\$
```

Type

```
PS1='\h:$PWD \u\$ '
```

That should change it (it works on my 10.11)

Comment: That changes it for the current terminal session. How can I do it automatically every time I fire up my terminal in Mac?